# NodeJS - Process Watcher

Tags: node.js

I was looking if there are any module that was able to start a process, in my case it would be a Binary File on a Unix system. I should be able to start, stop, restart and get the process status and if possible detect in real time when the process state changes (starting up or shutting down), I found some solutions but were not suitable, for example PM2 (they have a programmatically API) but I could not launch the binary file, I belive it only works for Node.js written applications. If someone knows a module or a simple and fast way to achieve this I would be thankfull.

Comment: It's a native module, right there in the documentation... [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/child_process.html)

Comment: I am able to monitor in real time the process status? I already tried child_process exec but I was looking for a already built solution for process management in Node